# Audio input SNR processing

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio

I'm new to audio processing and am trying to do what I thought would be a fairly simple task. I was wrong about that so I'm looking for a little direction.

This is an OS X desktop app. I am playing a single frequency tone (1kHz) while the tone is playing I want to use a selected input to listen to the tone and then calculate the signal to noise ratio based on that input.

I have tried to use AVFoundation and the Accelerate framework but that is has not been working for me. Before I jump down that rabbit whole to debug it. I am wondering if that is the best approach or should I be looking at the AVAudioEngine or The Amazing Audio Engine.

Of course if there are any examples of SNR audio processing I could look at that would be helpful as well.

Thanks in advance for shoving an audio noob in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, CoreAudio is not trivial, yet don't need high-level tools to capture a input signal and measure it. A single audio component instance of type:

```c
AudioComponentDescription audioCompDesc;
audioCompDesc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
audioCompDesc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput;
audioCompDesc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
audioCompDesc.componentFlags = 0;
audioCompDesc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
```

would do the job for you.

You must only know how to properly initialize it and handle the callback. Make sure to enable input, disable output on the *audio component instance*. You may set and use the *input callback* for capturing and measuring the signal and noise levels.
Going into detail of doing it would by far exceed the scope of this answer and purpose of this site, which is *not* a tutorial site.
Fortunately, you have lots of examples to learn all over the web. There is a 'cannot do without' [CoreAudio tutorial book](http://www.informit.com/store/learning-core-audio-a-hands-on-guide-to-audio-programming-9780321636843), where you can learn from code not very distant from what you need. Make sure to also read the Apple documentation on the AudioUnit and AudioToolbox API.

Do some individual research, then post back if you run across a specific, programming related problem.